# ActiveAdmin custom resource action (view and action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to make a form to edit one attribute of a resource. It seems like such a simple thing, but I'm dying out here. I have this code for processing it:

```
  member_action :revoke, method: :put do
    resource.update(suspended_at: params[:suspended_at])
    redirect_to resource_path, notice: 'Subscription revoked!'
  end
```

But where/how do I actually make the form?

I have tried this code:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register_page "Revoke" do
    belongs_to :payment_subscription, parent_class: Payment::Subscription
    content do
      semantic_form_for Payment::Subscription.find(params[:id]) do
        f.inputs do
          f.input :suspended_at, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { max_date: Date.today.iso8601 }
        end
        f.actions
      end
    end
  end
```

But it's throwing an error saying `Could not find Subscription in active_admin`, and honestly I don't know if I'm even in the right direction.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You could do this through a ``page_action`` dsl directive in the ``register_page`` block. Or you could to this with a ``member_action``, but this would have to be put in the ``ActiveAdmin`` resource file, probably located at ``app/admin/payment_subscriptions.rb`` . To be of any help, let me know if you have a working form for the payment_subscription and/or if you have working index views.

Comment: @SjorsBranderhorst the `register_page` code above is at the bottom of the resource file. I got it to work with this line `belongs_to "subscriptions", class_name: 'Payment::Subscription'`, and the form shows, but crashes when I try to submit—probably because it's trying to find a model called `Revoke`?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler to set it up without the separate `Page`. You can have 2 `member_action` blocks in the resource file. One would be method :get, the other method :post e.g.:

```
member_action :revoke, :method => :get do
  # this will render the template, if you don't know where to put it,
  # the rails log will tell you where rails is looking for it
end
```

Rake routes will help you find the spelling for the path helper, you will need this for the :action attribute . Put your custom form in the template.**a**rb (give it the .arb extension) you put your custom form:

```
form(:method => :post, :action => the_path_helper_that_you_just_saw_in_rake_routes_path) do # dont forget _path at   the end
  input(:type => :hidden, :name => 'authenticity_token', :value => form_authenticity_token)
 # your custom inputs
  input :type => :submit, :value => 'Revoke!'
end
```

Then you will have to `catch` the POST in the other `:member_action`:

```
member_action :revoke, :method => :post do
  # I stub it with this, to see if the POST will reach
  # raise params.inspect
  # your logic
  if true
    # flash message
    redirect_to where_you_want and return
  else 
    # flash message
    # either
    #   render the get member_action
    # or
    # redirect_to the_get_route and return
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured something out. Here's the full setup for future reference:

---

Adding a link to the page that will contain the form:

```
  action_item :revoke, only: :show, if: -> { !resource.state.suspended? } do
    link_to('Revoke', revoke_active_admin_payment_subscription_path(resource), method: :get)
  end
```

And the routes for GET (to render the form) and PUT (to update the model):

```
  member_action :revoke, method: [:get, :put] do
    if request.put?
      resource.model.update(suspended_at: params[:payment_subscription][:suspended_at])
      redirect_to resource_path, notice: 'Subscription revoked!'
    else
      render :revoke, locals: { resource: resource }
    end
  end
```

The GET will look for a view called `revoke.html.arb` within the `views/active_admin` directory:

```
active_admin_form_for resource.model,
  url: revoke_active_admin_payment_subscription_path(resource),
  method: :put do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :suspended_at, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { max_date: Date.today.iso8601 }
  end
  f.actions
end
```